# Solve the differential equation. stuck on integrating factor

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have this problem:

$$t^2 \frac{dy}{dt} + 3ty = \sqrt{1 + t^2}$$

I'm trying to get the equation in the form:

$$\frac{dy}{dt} + P(x)y = Q(x)$$

but dividing by t^2 leaves the right side in a strange form that doesn't seem reducible. What can I do here?

The integrating factor I know is $e^{\int P(X)}$

and then I can use that to multiply both sides and it allows me to setup an easy integration to then isolate y. How can I do this?

**EDIT**

Is this right?
$$ I(t) = e^{\int \frac{3}{t}dt} = e^{3ln{t}} = t^3$$

$$t^3 \frac{dy}{dt} + t^3 \frac{3}{t} y = t \sqrt{1 + t^2}$$

$$t^3 \frac{dy}{dt} + 3t^2* y = t \sqrt{1 + t^2}$$

$$(t^3y)' = t \sqrt{1 + t^2}$$

$$(t^3y) = \int t \sqrt{1 + t^2}$$

after u-subbing $u = 1 + t^2$ and $du = 2tdt$

$$(t^3y) = \frac{1}{3} (1 + t^2)^{\frac{3}{2}} + C$$

Is this the right path?

Comment: Divide both sides by $t^2$ anyways. Then $P(t) = \frac3t$ and $\mu(t) = t^3$. Then you multiply through by the integrating factor, $\mu$, and you'll get $(t^3y)' = t\sqrt{1+t^2}$. Easy peasy.

Comment: @Moo yes I did mean that

Comment: Yes!!! I have also done in that way.

Answer (score 1):

$t^2\frac{dy}{dt} + 3ty = \sqrt{1+t^2}$

Dividing throughout by $t^2$,
$$\frac{dy}{dt} +\frac{3y}{t} = \frac{\sqrt{1+t^2}}{t^2}$$

So,$$P(t) = 3/t, Q(t) = \frac{\sqrt{1+t^2}}{t^2}$$

$$IF = e^{\int{3/t}} = e^{3ln(t)} = e^{ln(t^3)} = t^3$$

Next,

$$y.IF = \int{Q(t).IF.dt} + c$$
$$y.t^3 = \int{\frac{\sqrt{1+t^2}}{t^2}.t^3.dt} +c$$
$$y.t^3  = \int{\sqrt{1+t^2}tdt} +c = \frac{1}{2}\int{\sqrt{1+t^2}d(1+t^2)} + c$$
(as, $d(1+t^2) = 2tdt$)

$$y.t^3 = \frac{1}{2}.\frac{2}{3}(1+t^2)^{3/2} + c = \frac{1 }{3}(1+t^2)^{3/2}+c$$

Answer (score 0):

Divide both sides by $t^2$ and notice that when $t=0$, the equation has no solutions. So, we're safe there.

$$
e^{\int\frac{3}{t}\,dt}=
e^{3\int\frac{1}{t}\,dt}=
e^{3\ln{|t|}}
e^{\ln{|t^3|}}=
|t^3|.
$$

$$
y=\frac{1}{|t^3|}\int\frac{\sqrt{1+t^2}}{t^2}|t^3|\,dt=
\frac{1}{|t^3|}\int |t|\sqrt{1+t^2}\,dt.
$$
If $t>0$, we have:
$$y=\frac{1}{t^3}\int t\sqrt{1+t^2}\,dt.$$
If $t<0$, we have:
$$y=\frac{1}{-t^3}\int (-t)\sqrt{1+t^2}\,dt=\frac{1}{t^3}\int t\sqrt{1+t^2}\,dt.$$
Both cases give equivalent results. Now, just use the u-substitution $u=1+t^2$:
$$
y=\frac{1}{t^3}\int t\sqrt{1+t^2}\,dt=
\frac{1}{2t^3}\int\sqrt{1+t^2}\frac{d}{dt}\left(1+t^2\right)\,dt=\\
\frac{1}{2t^3}\int\sqrt{u}\,du=\frac{1}{2t^3}\left(\frac{2\sqrt{u^3}}{3}+C\right)=\\
\frac{1}{2t^3}\left(\frac{2\sqrt{(1+t^2)^3}}{3}+C\right)=
\frac{\sqrt{(1+t^2)^3}+C}{3t^3}.
$$